# horizontal overlap on :before element in Firefox

Tags: css

I have a :before element on my footer that is giving it a "slanted" look. The issue is a horizontal scroll being caused from the `border-left: 2000px` below. Any suggestions on how to fix? `overflow: hidden;` doesn't do the trick.

```
footer:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    height: 0px;
    border-bottom: 70px solid #4A473D;
    border-left: 2000px solid transparent;
    margin-top: -70px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Does the footer have `position:relative`?

Comment: Why would you need a 2000px border?

Comment: add overflow:hidden to its parent div

Comment: I agree with @sticksu. Let's solve _that_ problem first, then this problem will almost certainly go away.